# How to check the first login of the FBA users in SharePoint site and ask them to fill the information

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, fba

I need to check the first login of the FBA users in SharePoint site and force them to fill a form of basic information. I have no idea how to do this. appreciated any help or suggestion in this matter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the users self-register - you could do it at registration time.  If not you could create a separate page to gather all of this information, and add a snippet of code to the master page that would check if the information has been filled out.  If not, it could redirect the user to this page you created.

Instead of checking if the information is filled out on the master page, you could customize the login page to check for the information after a successful login - however the login control can be very difficult to modify to do that.